# Using api to create json and print from list. Why am i getting index error when list is not empty

Tags: python, json

In trying to generate a list of words with a specific number of syllables from datamuse api, and choosing a random one of those words to print, I often recieve an index error while I know the list cannot possibly be empty. Each subsequent word relies on parameters pertaining to the previous word. My full code has 7 words but all are essentially a copy of the second word. With all 7 words, yes, a list will sometimes be empty, but in the case with only 2 words and the given parameters I don't understand why it is happenening.

```
`import json, requests, random


# FIRST WORD
related_word = input("word: ")
#create list for related words
parameters = {
    'rel_trg': related_word,
    'md': 's'  # Request the number of syllables for each word
}
response = requests.get('https://api.datamuse.com/words', params=parameters)
related = response.json()

three_syllable_words = [] # creates list for three syllable words

for word in related:
    num_syllables = word.get('numSyllables', 0)
    if num_syllables == 3:                          #filters list to only 3 syllable words
        three_syllable_words.append(word)       

#select random three_syllable_word
first_three_sylword = random.choice(three_syllable_words)
first_word = first_three_sylword['word'] #use only word data
#print(first_word)

# Second Word
parameters2 = {
    'rel_rhy':first_word,  # Rhymes
    'lc':first_word,  # Left context to the original word entered by the user
    'md': 's'  # Request the number of syllables for each word
    }

response2 = requests.get('https://api.datamuse.com/words', params=parameters2)
lcrhyme = response2.json()

two_syllable_words = []

for word in lcrhyme:
    num_syllables = word.get('numSyllables', 0)
    if num_syllables == 3:
        two_syllable_words.append(word)


first_two_syl_word = random.choice((two_syllable_words))
second_word = first_two_syl_word['word']
print(second_word, first_word)`
```

Comment: what word results in the error?

Answer (score 1):

> I often recieve an index error while I know the list cannot possibly be empty.

Why do you think so?

```py
response = requests.get('https://api.datamuse.com/words', params=parameters)
related = response.json()

print(related)

three_syllable_words = [] # creates list for three syllable words

for word in related:
    num_syllables = word.get('numSyllables', 0)
    if num_syllables == 3:                          #filters list to only 3 syllable words
        three_syllable_words.append(word)       

#select random three_syllable_word
first_three_sylword = random.choice(three_syllable_words)
```

What do you think happens if `related` is empty?

Try

```py
random.choice([])
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @daviid in the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77202235/218663), the issue is that sometimes the API cannot find "related" or "rhyming" words for a given word. In those cases, calls to `random.choice()` get passed an empty list and that is going to throw the error you see.

You need to guard against those instances. Perhaps like:

```py
word  = random.choice(words)["word"] if words else ""
```

Here is how I might initially address the task:

```py
import random
import requests

def get_related_rhyme(word, related_syllables=3, rhyme_syllables=2):
    related_word = get_related_word(word, related_syllables)
    related_rhyme = get_rhyming_word(related_word, rhyme_syllables)
    return (related_word, related_rhyme)

def get_related_word(word, syllables):
    if not word or not syllables:
        return ""

    url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words"
    parameters = {"rel_trg": word, "md": "s"}
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    words = response.json()
    return get_random_word(words, syllables)

def get_rhyming_word(word, syllables):
    if not word or not syllables:
        return ""

    url = "https://api.datamuse.com/words"
    parameters = {"rel_rhy":word, "lc":word, "md": "s"}
    response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
    words = response.json()
    return get_random_word(words, syllables)

def get_random_word(words, syllables):
    syllable_words = [
        word
        for word
        in words
        if word.get("numSyllables", 0) == syllables
    ]
    return random.choice(syllable_words)["word"] if syllable_words else ""

TEMPLATE = '''word: "{w}", related: "{rw}", related rhyme: "{rr}"'''

word = "parkinglot"
related_word, related_rhyme = get_related_rhyme(word)
print(TEMPLATE.format(w=word, rw=related_word, rr=related_rhyme))

word = "apartment"
related_word, related_rhyme = get_related_rhyme(word)
print(TEMPLATE.format(w=word, rw=related_word, rr=related_rhyme))
```

That will likely give you a result like:

```
word: "parkinglot", related: "", related rhyme: ""
word: "apartment", related: "manhattan", related rhyme: "patin"
```